# using input type with react

Tags: reactjs, input

I'm write application with react, and I have a issue to use the tag input

```
enter code here:import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

enter code here :import { Formik } from 'formik';

```
enter code here:export class Login   extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="form">

  <form>
 <div class="inputemail">
    <label class="labelinput" for="">email or phone</label>
    <input class="input" type="text">
    <div class="inputpassword">
    <label class="labelinput" for="">Password</label>
    <input class ="input"value  type="password">
    <a class="linkpassword" href="#">forget password?</a>
    <input class="inputbtn" type="submit"  value="entrar">enter</input>
                </input>
                 </div>
    </input>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  )
};
```

}

export default Login;

when the react don't accept the tag input. someone know why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

you have a sintax error in your code and your missing closing tags, use this:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="logo" />
          <div class="form">
            <form>
              <div class="inputemail">
                <label class="labelinput" for="">
                  email or phone
                </label>
                <input class="input" type="text" />
                <div class="inputpassword">
                  <label class="labelinput" for="">
                    Password
                  </label>
                  <input class="input" value type="password" />
                  <a class="linkpassword" href="#">
                    forget password?
                  </a>
                  <input class="inputbtn" type="submit" value="enter" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to use `className=""` instead of `class=""`.
Second, You have an unclosed input `<input class="input" type="text">` You have to close it first. 
And the last part is also inappropriate for react.

```
<input class="inputbtn" type="submit"  value="entrar">enter</input>
                </input>
```

Please clean your HTML firstly. All tags have to be closed. Even such as  and 
 
If this doesn't solve the problem, please send us your error.

Comment: In react you have to close all of your tags.
p.s. Please give us your error message

Comment: Please do read the [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), `<input type="text" name="name" />` is a valid input, `<input type="text" name="name" >` is not. The `/` in the end closes the tag.